# regex for testing "\" in string

Tags: regex

Why this regexp returns **false**  for

```
/[\\]/igm.test('asdasdasd\asdasd');
```

and **true** for

```
/[\\]/igm.test('asdasdasd\\asdasd');
```

and when I try this it gives error, why..?

```
/[\\]/igm.test('abc\xyz');
```

Comment: On which platform is this?

Comment: `\a` is a character, `\\a` is the character ` \ ` followed by `a` . As for the error, I do not know.

Comment: I am executing it on chrome console

Comment: @LupuSilviu I dont understand why "\a" will be a character as "a" is not a notation in regex

Comment: @Mr.A `\a matches the bell character (ASCII 7)`. This is that regex translates \a to.

Answer (score 0):

`\x` is a character escape for an ASCII character, where the next two characters must be hexidecimal digits. So, `\xyz` is invalid because y and z aren't hex digits.